# Apache Camel: best practice how to consume data from multiple REST endpoints

Tags: java, apache-camel

I am consuming data from REST endpoints (order of 1000+) which all have the same structure:

```
<server uri>/v1/source/<some ID>
```

I am using RouteBuilder components like this connecting to the individual endpoint `<ID>`:

```
@Component
public class Route_to_<ID> extends RouteBuilder {

@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
    from("timer:mytimer?repeatCount=1") //
            .setBody(simple("${null}")) //
            .setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, simple("text/event-stream"))
            .setHeader("CamelHttpMethod", simple("GET"))
            .to(
                    <server uri>/v1/source/<ID>
                            + _deviceName + "::" + _deviceProperty //
                            + "?disableStreamCache=true" //
            ) //
            .process(data -> {
                ... do same stuff for all endpoints ...
            });
}
```

}

The corresponding `SpringBootApplication`looks like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "my.package.where.components.reside")
public class MyRouteHandler {

}
```

Is there an elegant way to start all the individual routes to endpoints `<ID>`in one go using one single `SpringBootApplication`? Or does every route need an individual `SpringBootApplication` which is to be started individually?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [toD](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/eips/toD-eip.html) with dynamic uri that gets the **version**, **source** and **id** from message body, headers or exchange properties. You can also use [property-placeholders](https://camel.apache.org/manual/using-propertyplaceholder.html) to define host, port and other configs.

Since the REST endpoints all use the same structure you can change the **version**, **source** and **id** and use the same URI for most if not all the REST API calls.

**Example:**

```java
public class ExampleTest extends CamelTestSupport {
    
    static final String API_DYNAMIC_URI = "https://{{api.uri}}:{{api.port}}/{{api.version}}" 
        + "/${exchangeProperty.source}/${exchangeProperty.id}"
        + "?disableStreamCache=true";

    @Test
    public void exampleTest() throws Exception {

        context.adviceWith(context.getRouteDefinition("exampleRoute"), 
            new AdviceWithRouteBuilder(){

            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {

                weaveById("apiEndpoint")
                    .replace()
                    .toD("mock:${exchangeProperty.source}/${exchangeProperty.id}")
                    .setBody().simple("Source: ${exchangeProperty.source} id: ${exchangeProperty.id}");
            } 
        });        

        Map<String, Object> body1 = new HashMap<>();
        body1.put("source", "source1");
        body1.put("id", "A");

        Map<String, Object> body2 = new HashMap<>();
        body2.put("source", "source2");
        body2.put("id", "B");

        MockEndpoint source1MockEndpoint = getMockEndpoint("mock:source1/A");
        source1MockEndpoint.expectedMessageCount(1);

        MockEndpoint source2MockEndpoint = getMockEndpoint("mock:source2/B");
        source2MockEndpoint.expectedMessageCount(2);
        
        startCamelContext();
        template.sendBody("direct:start", body1);
        
        template.sendBody("direct:start", body2);
        template.sendBody("direct:start", body2);

        source1MockEndpoint.assertIsSatisfied();
        source2MockEndpoint.assertIsSatisfied();
    }

    @Override
    protected RoutesBuilder createRouteBuilder() throws Exception {
        
        return new RouteBuilder() {

            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
             
                from("direct:start")
                    .routeId("exampleRoute")
                    .setProperty("source").simple("${body['source']}")
                    .setProperty("id").simple("${body['id']}")
                    .toD(API_DYNAMIC_URI).id("apiEndpoint")
                    .log("Received: ${body}");
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    protected Properties useOverridePropertiesWithPropertiesComponent() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("api.uri", "localhost");
        properties.put("api.port", "3000");
        properties.put("api.version", "v1");
        return properties;
    }
 
    @Override
    public boolean isUseAdviceWith() {
        return true;
    }
}
```